# How at once change properties of multiple elements in the Container in WPF code (VB)

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, properties, element

On the Grid, there are many different elements. From all of them I need to select only ellipses and change their properties. Ellipses are placed on their own canvases, and those canvases are in few viewboxes,...

I think of something like this:
In the code (not xaml), define empty list and fill it with all ellipses placed in MainGrid container.
Than change the property of every ellipse in the list. Or is there other way? Example bellow is just "free hand" Maybe if someone will tuneup the "syntax" it will work. I cant, I am too new explorer to WPF...

```
 Dim elipslist As New List(Of Ellipse)
 For Each elem In MainGrid(Elements)
        If (elem.GetType() Is GetType(Ellipse)) Then elipslist.Add(elem)
 Next
 For Each elip In elipslist
        Height = "30" Width="30" Fill="#FF000000"
 Next
```

Comment: I don't think there's necessarily anything wrong conceptually with your code.  You would need to cast `elem` to `Ellipse` to add it to the list; I'd suggest using `TryCast` then you can combine your test and cast into the same operation.  `Height` and `Width` are probably `Integer` in code instead of strings.

Comment: The original code comes form my VB WinForm application. 
I have just freely replaced texts:

original  Dim rbs As New List(Of RadioButton) 
with      Dim elipslist As New List(Of Ellipse)
original  For Each ct In Groupbox.Controls
with      For Each elem In MainGrid(Elements)
and so on. 

But my problem for now is, that I dont know how to write it in correct syntax for WPF even with help of intellisense.
Task is not hard, but I am not able to rewrite for WPF, not familiar with new classes names and so.
I am learning from working examples :)

Answer (score 0):

Finnaly I found what i was searching for.
For example a code line from WinForms:

```
For Each ctrl In Groupbox.Controls
```

asked  with:

```
For Each elem In MainGrid(Elements)
```

in WPF should look like:

```
For Each elem In MainGrid.Children
```